# NodeJS - return response as a process continue working anyways

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I have an async method which invokes a few calls (await promise....) in a loop,
and eventually returns a result.
When I get the result from that function, I send back a response to the client.
What I have to do is to return a response in the middle of the process/loop,
while the loop continue running.
Of course it breaks the loop, since it returns from the function in the middle of the loop.

Here is a piece of code to demonstrate.

```
app.post('/test', async (req, res)=>{
    const body = JSON.stringify(req.body)
    await doSomething()
    res.status(200).send("ok");
});

const doSomething = async () => {
    let times = 0;
    for(let i=0 ; i<5 ; i++){
        console.log(i)
        await delay(1000);
        if(i==2){
            return 2;
        }
    }
    return times;  
}

const delay = async (ms) => {
    return await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

When I get i==2, I want to return a value and response to the client,
but I still want the loop to run till the end.
I thought to use some observer which will be responsible for returning a response,
(say rxjs, event emitter, etc...). Not sure what is the best practice for such
a different situation.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: can do it a few ways, simplest is to pass res.status as a callback into doSomething then instead of `return 2` call the callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use a synchronous function and return a `Promise`.  But AFAIK making the callback passed to the Promise constructor async won't work:

```js
const doSomething = () => {
    let times = 0;
    return new Promise(async (resolveMain) => {
        for(let i=0 ; i<5 ; i++){
            console.log(i)
            await delay(1000);
            if(i==2){
                resolveMain(2);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

It's also twisted LOL.

So I'm sure there are many other ways to accomplish this, but I'm assuming you want to keep the `await delay(1000);`. What you're gong to need is an async generator function.

```js
app.post('/test', async (req, res)=>{
    const body = JSON.stringify(req.body)
    await doSomething()
    res.status(200).send("ok");
});

async function* doLoopyThing(){
    let times = 0;
    for(let i=0 ; i<5 ; i++){
        console.log(i)
        await delay(1000);
        if(i==2){
            yield 2;
        }
    }      
}

function doSomething(){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const looper = doLoopyThing();
        looper.next().then(({value}) => resolve(value));
        looper.next();
    }
}
```

This is also twisted, but it should work.

> I don't understand how this can possibly be the right way to actually accomplish something. But I'm assuming the is just for fun, or  you're trying to learn.
>
> Also if all you were trying to show with the `await delay(1000)` was a heavy function, and you don't actually need the function to be asynchronous, the first solution should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy, I solved using you solution :-D